# RecursiveDirectoryIterator: failed to open dir: Too many open files

Tags: php

De volta e meia, sem que consiga recolher dados para entender o que poderá estar por trás disto, recebo o seguinte erro:

> RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(caminho/para/directoria) [recursivedirectoryiterator.--construct]: failed to open dir: Too many open files

O servidor onde este erro surge está a correr Apache/2.2.24 e PHP/5.3.22.

```
$workingPath = "caminho/para/directoria";

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($workingPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

$files = iterator_to_array($iterator, true); /* tentativa de abafar o erro
                                                como sugerido num tópico do SOEN
                                                mas sem sucesso em resolver a questão */

foreach ($files as $file) {
  // código a executar por cada ficheiro localizado
}
```

## Pergunta

Como posso avaliar correctamente a causa deste erro e/ou descobrir se existem limites que desconheço que possam estar a causar o mesmo?

Comment: @Bacco Não estou a indicar nada nesse sentido... Na verdade assumi que após cada passo do ciclo o próprio iterador iria fechar o ficheiro anterior!

Comment: @Bacco Esse exemplo é o mesmo código que uso na pergunta, mas eu estou a passar um parâmetro ao iterador. A minha conversão do iterador para matriz é um passo que apenas apliquei para ver se resolvia a questão. Em relação ao `foreach()` vs `while()`, não me parece que venha dai o problema, mas vou testar...

Comment: Tente tambem a flag "FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS" no DirectoryIterator pra ele nao entrar em "recursão da recursão": `RecursiveDirectoryIterator($workingPath,FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)` (nao sei se ajuda, nunca usei esses iteradores)

Comment: @Bacco Eu li esse tópico, mas no local onde o iterador está a ser executado, é uma localização temporária que tem até 6 ficheiros no máximo :/ Por isso... não sei...

Comment: Mas e a árvore? Você esta usando RecursiveDirectoryIterator, e não DirectoryIterator, então ele está indo nas subpastas.

Comment: Deixei a tradução da resposta aí embaixo, caso seja útil pra outra pessoa. Se for outro caso, deleto, e/ou você pode por uma resposta correta assim que descobrir. Se eu pensar mais alguma coisa, aviso. Vou deletar os comments de cima, depois deleto esse aqui.

Comment: Se puder, faça um teste com DirectoryIterator no lugar do RecursiveDirectoryIterator só pra ver se o erro muda.

Comment: @Bacco A operação é para ir à pasta principal e às suas sub-pastas, localizando um determinado ficheiro e _thumbnails_! No máximo são 5 pastas pelo que dá um total de 6 ficheiros. Mas estou a fazer testes...

Answer (score 2):

Isto pode ser uma limitação do servidor onde o código está rodando. Cada OS permite um certo número de arquivos/handles/sockets. Geralmente este número é reduzido quando o servidor é virtualizado. Em um servidor Linux você pode checar o limite atual com `ulimit -n`, e se tiver acesso *root* pode aumentar o limite com o mesmo comando. Teoricamente o Windows deve ter meios de configurar isto também. Não tendo estas possibilidades, não há muito o que fazer, senão pedir para o administrador do host aumentar estes limites.

Limites configuráveis:

- Em /etc/security/limits.conf

  soft nofile 1024 
    hard nofile 65535
- Aumente o ulimit com "ulimit -n 65535" ou

  echo 65535 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max
- Em /etc/sysctl.conf

  fs.file-max=65535

Original :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748499/fatal-error-too-many-open-files